# Replace an image at the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am looking to replace a particular image when i click on it and change it to active image. but then i click on any other image, the clicked image becomes active and the other image becomes inactive again.

the html markup looks like this:

the HTML that i am using is:

```
<ul id="weeklyPrizeBlockThumb">
      <li class="active"> <img src="images/bts/bts_overlay_wp_box_thumbw1.jpg" alt="Week1" id="week1" />
        <p class="text"> <span>Gearing Up for School:</span> <span>$100 of Mead® School Supplies!1</span></p>
      </li>
      <li> <img src="images/bts/bts_overlay_wp_box_thumbw2.jpg" alt="Week2" id="week2" />
        <p class="text"> <span>Sticking to a Schedule:</span> <span>$100 Gift Card from The Container Store®!</span></p>
      </li>
      <li> <img src="images/bts/bts_overlay_wp_box_thumbw3.jpg" alt="Week3" id="week3" />
        <p class="text"> <span>Doing Lunch:</span> <span>Soft Lunch Bag with $100 of Unilever Products!</span></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

The JS is:

```
    var src1 = $('ul#weeklyPrizeBlockThumb li').find('img').attr("src").replace("_active.jpg", ".jpg");
    $('ul#weeklyPrizeBlockThumb li').find('img').attr("src", src1);

    //$('#overlay_wp_weekImg div').find('img').attr("src").replace("_active", "");
    var src = $(this).find('img').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_active.jpg";
$(this).find('img').attr("src", src);
```

this is not working correctly. it does not de-active-ate the previous images.

Comment: It would be way easier and a lot less code to have two images in the page next to each other and just hide one, show the other at the appropriate time.  Give each an appropriate ID and it's like two simple lines of code in the click handler.  But, I agree with Ibu, we can't help you without seeing the click event handlers and the code that they run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this~

```
$(function(){
$("#weeklyPrizeBlockThumb li").each(function(){
var li = $(this);
    li.click(function(){
        $("#weeklyPrizeBlockThumb>li>img").each(function(index){
            $(this).attr("src","images/bts/bts_overlay_wp_box_thumbw"+ (index + 1) +".jpg");
            alert($(this).attr("src"));
        })
        li.find("img").attr("src","images/bts/_active.jpg");
        alert(li.find("img").attr("src"));
    })
})
})
```